# How to sync N processes to wait for each other through semaphore

Tags: c, linux, process, semaphore

Linux, C.

I have to sync N processes that are forked from one parent.

Every process needs to wait until all other processes have completed a task before they can all move to the second task simultaneously.

I was thinking about implementing a **semaphore** but I don't really know which type and how to implement it in an effective way.

Can anybody show me a way of doing this?

Does anyone have solutions to this issue?

Here is some pseudo-code of what I am trying to achieve:

```
for (int i = 0; i < init_people; ++i) {

    switch (pids[i] = fork()) {
        case -1:
            exit(1);
            break;
        case 0:
            switch (i % 2) {
                case 0:

                    /*Here is where one of the processes starts and 
                    does his task*/ 

                    execve("./A",args,NULL);

                    /*Here is where it stops and waits for all the 
                    other processes to complete the task*/

                    break;

                case 1:

                    /*Here is where one of the processes starts and 
                    does his task*/

                    execve("./B",args,NULL);
                    break;

                    /*Here is where it stops and waits for all the 
                    other processes to complete the task*/

                default:
                    break;
            }
            exit(0);
            break;

        default:
            waitpid(pids[i], &returnStatus, 0);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: ... and Linux has a barrier implementation already in the form of `pthread_barrier_t` and its associated `pthread_barrier_init()`, `*_destroy()`, and `*_wait()` functions.  Or are you required to implement your own?

Comment: You don't want a semaphore, you want a `pthread_barrier_t` allocated in shared memory and with its `pshared` attribute set to `PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED`.

Comment: @John Bollinger I am not required to implement anything

Comment: And how can I implement that @EOF

Comment: @BryanShtjefni Your two comments seem to be contradictory. Could you clarify?

Comment: I don't know how to specify things, I just know that I need to sync these processes in a way that they all wait for each other to move on to their other task @EOF

Comment: What you need is called a "thread barrier". Linux has them (or at least pthreads does). The other comments are trying to point you toward the pthreads implementation, but they're not going to write the code for you.

Comment: I would really like to learn more about this stuff but I am on a bit of a tight schedule and would really appreciate if somebody could give me a working example.

Answer (score 0):

> Every process needs to wait until all other processes have completed a task before they can all move to the second task simultaneously.
>
> I was thinking about implementing a **semaphore** …

Yes, you can *implement it in an effective way* with a [System V semaphore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/semget.2.html) that is initialized to the number N of processes, decremented by each process when its first task is completed and waited for becoming zero, before moving on to the second task. I completed (and changed where advisable) your pseudo-code.

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main()
{
    #define N   2
    const int init_people = N;
    pid_t pids[N];
    char *task[N] = { "./A 1", "./B 1" };
    char *second_task[N] = { "./A 2", "./B 2" };
    int sem = semget(IPC_PRIVATE, 1, S_IRWXU);  // create a semaphore
    semctl(sem, 0, SETVAL, init_people);        // initialize the value to N
    for (int i = 0; i < init_people; ++i)
        switch (pids[i] = fork())
        {
        case -1:
            exit(1);
        case 0:
            /*Here is where each of the processes starts and
            does his task*/ 
            system(task[i]);    // execve wouldn't return
            /*Here is where it stops and waits for all the 
            other processes to complete the task*/
            // decrement the semaphore value
            semop(sem, &(struct sembuf){.sem_op=-1}, 1);
            // wait until value is zero
            while (semop(sem, &(struct sembuf){}, 1) < 0)
                if (errno != EINTR) perror("semop"), exit(1);
            /*Here all move to the second task simultaneously*/
            system(second_task[i]);
            exit(0);
        }
    do ; while (wait(NULL) > 0);
    if (errno != ECHILD) perror("wait");
    semctl(sem, 0, IPC_RMID);   // remove the semaphore
}
```